# d3.js mouseover overlapping element

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I have a problem in solving the d3.js overlapping. Here is my situation

1. A PDF has converted to SVG. [Completed by Inkscape]
2. Around 30000 elements in the SVG file. (About 8MB).
3. Loading the SVG into the Browser using d3.js [Done]
4. Element will be highlighted when mouseover [Partially done]

My code is as follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var svg;
    var t;
    var zoomLevel = 2;
    var dz = 1;
    var path;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var loader = d3.xml('imgs/drawing4.svg', function (xml) {
            $('#mainDrawing').append(xml.documentElement);
            svg = d3.select('#layer1');
            t = d3.transform(svg.attr('transform'));
            zoomLevel = t.scale[0];
            var group = d3.select('#g2995');
            d3.select('#path2997').remove();

            path = group.selectAll('path')
                .on('mouseover', function () {
                    var self = d3.select(this);
                    self.style('fill', 'orange');
                })
                .on('mouseout', function () {
                    var self = d3.select(this);
                    self.style('fill', 'red');
                });
            });

            $('#zoomOut').click(function () {
                if (zoomLevel > 0.1)
                    zoomLevel -= dz / 10;
                svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + t.translate + ") scale(" + zoomLevel + ")");

            });

            $('#zoomIn').click(function () {
                if (zoomLevel < 2)
                    zoomLevel += dz / 10;
                svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + t.translate + ") scale(" + zoomLevel + ")");
            });
    });    
</script>
```

Thanks alot
Ken

---

Another picture showing some elements are overlapping (In inkscape select all element).
[Picture 1](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-njWCDpNukgg/U2L2mKhifJI/AAAAAAAACqs/8eDKe9QK58Q/w1044-h511-no/snap1.PNG)

When mouse over, the element is highlighted. (The picture is render in Firefox)! [Picture 2](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-fCXco4_Sris/U2L2mvaI_fI/AAAAAAAACq4/yWMt4XzxbB8/w1044-h489-no/snap4.png)

The problem is that I can't not select the lower elements (mainly path) SSB51 
Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry I don't have time to give a detailed answer, but it would do you good to create an svg tag with an identifier and attach your svg to it. Then, create an ordinary javascript mouseover for the svg tag and within the mouseover event, use d3 to select the svg and set its attributes.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're looking for please? Do you want to highlight any element on mouseover? Where does the overlapping come in? How is your current implementation partial?

Comment: Thanks Nav & Lars, I attached more information in my original question